# MongoDB - Can't be able to open Admin web interface through port: 28017

Tags: mongodb

I created a service for windows to run MongoDb. I found out port 27017 properly working and  I can make query against the database. But I am not able to open web interface for admin via port:28017. I am not sure what is the issue, i am new to Mongo, can anyone please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start your service with the argument `--httpinterface`.

Comment: Currently I have service running for mongodb, so what exact command I need to run? Could you please specify?

Comment: I am running service with the simple command net start mongodb

Comment: Run `services.msc` and look for your mongodb-Service. Right click and edit the service, add `--httpinterface` to its start parameters. Stop and start the service and check for the admin interface again.

Comment: Thanks, I did not find it in the document and int the installation guide section